# What to do when Record button is not working in UFT?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, integration-testing, qtp, hp-uft

**I have downloaded UFT 14 trial version and when I press the record button following error occurred**

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: UFT has crashed.  If this happens repeatedly, try reinstalling the application and make sure all dependencies were met

Answer (score -1):

Spy the  object with object spy utility and add objects into object repositories. from object repositories you can drag the object into your action. for more information about object spy , follow the below link : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/qtp/qtp_object_spy.htm .